# Access rendered items

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Playing around with Slickgrid. But got some questions that I'm not figurate out.

I have made an Regex filter on two X cells, and it works surprisingly well.
But for every time you filter or make other actions i want to flash all incorrect fields with cellFlash or highlighter.

Atm i have made a formatter with same regex as filter uses but it seems not 100% correct.
The problem when i'm using cellFlash is that it trigger the animation on ALL rows not only the rows thats rendered.

I'm not sure that i'm triggering the flashcell on correct callback/stage, I did it on my filter function i saved all incorrect rows in an array then i loop them throught and trigger flash.

So is it possible to get all items thats rendered in Viewport? Haven't find any information about this. Only data i can get out from getRenderedViewport.. is pxls. getRenderedRange() or getViewport()..

Comment: Please show examples of you code in addition to your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do processing on each data item in the current slick grid viewport, you can use `getRenderedRange()` to get the range of data item indexes that are rendered. You could then use that to get each visible data item

```
function forEachItemInViewport(fn) {
    var range = slickGrid.getRenderedRange();
    var bottom = range.bottom;

    while(bottom--) {
        var dataItem = slickGrid.getDataItem(bottom);
        fn(dataItem);
    }
}

forEachItemInViewport(function (item) {
    // do your work on each item in viewport
});
```